# Exception while starting the tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, tomcat7, terracotta

I am using maven tomcat7 plugin to start the tomcat locally. 
When I start the tomcat it gives me a build error with the following exception...

```
017-03-07 19:48:55,270 INFO - Terracotta Enterprise 3.7.10, as of 20150306-091518 (Revision 42990-26157 by jenkins-slave@tc-c65-jenkins-slave-001.eur.ad.sag from 3.7.10)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "HttpClientEvictionThread" Exception in thread "HttpClientEvictionThread"   Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "Thread-42" Exception in thread "non stop reaper thread"
```

I am not able to find any solution for this as there is no mention about this exception anywhere! 
Please help me figure out the issue.

TIA

Comment: Your code, as well as the command you use might be useful here

Comment: Please provide more context. What are you trying to build? Which version?